# Python Delete a key from a dictionary with multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary which looks like the following:

```
dictionary={('a','b'):1,('c','d'):2}
```

As you can see there are multiple keys for a value. What I would like to do is basically drop (delete) one of the keys. For example, I want to say that all values will not need the first key anymore and convert the above dictionary to the following:

```
dictionary={'b':1,'d':2}
```

What would be the safest way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Does the second member in each key occur only once?

Comment: There is **exactly one** key for each value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension* dropping the first item in each tuple:

```
dictionary = {k: v for (_, k), v in dictionary.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like assuming the structure of keys. To make it absolutely bomb-proof

```
from collections import Iterable
d = {
    k[-1] if isinstance(k, Iterable) else k: v
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have keys that are not lists or tuples, you will want to use this:

```
d ={('a','b'):1,('c','d'):2}

new_d = {a[-1] if isinstance(a, tuple) or isinstance(a, list) else a:b for a, b in d.items()}
```

Comment: You seem to have the ternary mixed up. It should immediately follow the key not the value. See what happens when `d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.